# Loading data async with queue. Proper write only locking and scheduling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have to store and return data on multitasking requests. If data is missing, I schedule loading and return null. I'm using some nubie scheduling by saving current jobs in a list. Also I need data request to be locked during writing. .NET 4.0

How can I schedule and lock properly?

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, IDataSet> data;
private List<string> loadingNow;

public IDataSet GetData(string dataId)
{
    if (loadingNow.Contains(dataId))
        return null; // Currently loading. Return null

    if (data.ContainsKey(dataId))
        return data[dataId]; // Return data

    // Schedule loading async. Return null.
    loadingNow.Add(dataId);
    dataIoAsync.LoadDataAsync(dataParams);
    return null;
}

private void DataIoAsync_DataFileLoaded(object sender, DataFileLoadedAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    loadingNow.Remove(e.DataId);
    data.TryAdd(e.DataId, e.DataSet);
    OnDataFileLoaded(e.DataId);
}
```

EDIT: Dictionary replaced with ConcurrentDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of what's being loaded, you can represent that as a state by wrapping `IDataSet` into a class:

```
private sealed class DataSetResult
{
    public volatile IDataSet Result;
}
```

When an instance of this class is created, start loading the data. You can then just return the value of the `Result` field - if it is `null`, the data is still being loaded:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<DataSetResult>> _data;

public IDataSet GetData(string dataId)
{
    var dataSet = _data.GetOrAdd(
        dataId, 
        _ => new Lazy<DataSetResult>(
            () =>
            {
                var result = new DataSetResult();
                dataIoAsync.LoadDataAsync(dataParams);
                return result;
            }
        )
    );

    return dataSet.Value.Result;
}

private void DataIoAsync_DataFileLoaded(object sender, DataFileLoadedAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    _data[e.DataId].Value.Result = e.DataSet;
    OnDataFileLoaded(e.DataId);
}
```

The `Lazy<DataSetResult>` above ensures that data is retrieved at most once for a given id.

Personally, however, I would prefer to return `Task<IDataSet>` from this method, as it is really up to the caller to decide whether they want to wait for the result to become available or not. Using `Task` also allows you to report any exceptions to the client:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<TaskCompletionSource<IDataSet>>> _data;

public Task<IDataSet> GetDataAsync(string dataId)
{
    var dataSet = _data.GetOrAdd(
        dataId, 
        _ => new Lazy<TaskCompletionSource<IDataSet>>(
            () =>
            {
                var result = new TaskCompletionSource<IDataSet>();
                dataIoAsync.LoadDataAsync(dataParams);
                return result;
            }
        )
    );

    return dataSet.Value.Task;
}

private void DataIoAsync_DataFileLoaded(object sender, DataFileLoadedAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    _data[e.DataId].Value.TrySetResult(e.DataSet);
    OnDataFileLoaded(e.DataId);
}
```

Comment: It's very interesting. I have tried something similar. Storing null dataSet in _data, but there was a side effect. This wrapping may solve the problem. I have to read further about Lazy<DataSetResult>. I'll test your solution.